# How to Change footer value in antd layout when i click on button inside route based component in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

[image]

I have used antd Layout with footer for Reactjs application. How to change value of footer when I click on button inside numbers component. I have used antd layout like this

https://ant.design/components/layout/

Code For Above Functionality Like:

When i click on button how to display Input value on Footer Label.
Mainly Two component Like :

1. WebSiteLayout.js (Footer inside them)
2. NumberList.js (Button and Input value inside them)

How to pass value from NumberList.js component to WebSiteLayout.js

WebSiteLayout.js

```
import React from "react";
import { withRouter, Switch, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import NumbersList from "../pages/Numbers/NumbersList";
import AuthenticatedRoute from '../../AuthenticatedRoute';
import './WebLayout.css';
import '../../../../assets/css/app.css';
import { Layout, Button, Menu, Popover, Spin, Select, Checkbox, Row, Col, Form, notification } from 'antd';
const { Header, Sider, Content, Footer } = Layout;
const { SubMenu } = Menu;
import {
  PhoneOutlined,
} from '@ant-design/icons';

const WebSiteLayout = ({ location, row }) => {
    return (
        <Layout>
          <Sider trigger={null} collapsible collapsed={collapsed}>
            <div className="topbar1">
              <div className="topbar-left">
              </div>
            </div>
            <Menu theme="dark" mode="inline">
              <Menu.Item key="/numbers" icon={<PhoneOutlined style={{ fontSize: '18px' }} />} title="Numbers" >
                <span>Numbers</span>
                <Link to="/numbers" />
              </Menu.Item>
               </Menu> 
          </Sider>
          <Layout className="site-layout" hasSider={true} style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
            <Content
              className="site-layout-background"
              style={{
                padding: 24,
                height: '80px',
                minHeight: 280,
              }}
            >
              <Switch>
                <AuthenticatedRoute path='/numbers' component={NumbersList} />
              </Switch>
                <Footer style={{ position: "fixed", bottom: "0px", right: "0px", background: "#c2c2c2", padding: "15px 25px" }}>
                  Display Numbers Field Value
                </Footer>
            </Content>
          </Layout>
        </Layout>
               );
};
export default withRouter(WebSiteLayout)
```

NumberList.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
import { Button, Input } from 'antd';

class NumbersList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value:''
    }
  }

  sendValueToFooter = () => {
      console.log(this.state.value);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="container-fluid">
              <h4 class="page-title float-left">Numbers</h4>
              <Input placeholder="Basic usage" value={this.state.value} onChange={(e)=>{this.setState({value : e.target.value})}}/>
                <br></br>
                <Button type="primary" onClick={this.sendValueToFooter}>
                  Click Here To Send Value On Footer
                </Button>

       </div>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(NumbersList)
```

When I click on button how to display Input value on Footer Label.

Comment: You can make use of - https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: The Context API could help. There is also [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) where you add some state to `WebSiteLayout` for the "Display Numbers Field Value" value, pass a callback to `NumbersList` component to handle passing the value back out. Note though that this would likely require you to rewrite your `AuthenticatedRoute` to allow being able to pass extra props through to the component, see [Route render prop](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func). Seeing as how `NumberList` uses `withRouter` I'm going to guess it doesn't pass route props.